# Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing on mobile View

Tags: html, css, navbar

Working With Bootstrap Navbar Item not Collapsing on Mobile View 
I just added navbar-fixed-top. i want to know whats wrong with mycode
and Want solution for it

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-nav navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a class="scrollable" href="#top">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="scrollable" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a class="scrollable" href="#contact">Contact Info</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


</header>
```

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap javascript file?

Comment: jqury missing or view port meta tag.

Comment: @MarkC. No I missed on that one Thanks

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi. Thank you too Bro Bootstrap Js was missing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to include jquery and bootstrap.min.js for collapsing navbar

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-nav navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a class="scrollable" href="#top">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="scrollable" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a class="scrollable" href="#contact">Contact Info</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


</header>
```